# If the inherited class can work as the base class but never use it because it shouldn't, is it still an 'is-a' relationship?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I already finished the implementation I wanted, but I was wondering if this is the right way. I'm confused about the 'is-a' relationship in inheritance.

**Background:**
I wanted to put a `QStackedWidget` with four widget pages in the main window.
However, as I implemented it, I realized that I need common functions of pages, such as moving to the next or previous or first page, or moving to the first page when a timeout is triggered after a certain period of time. So I decided to create a parent widget from which my custom widget would inherit.

So, my code like:

```
// pageWidget.h
// this parent class has no UI
class pageWidget : public QWidget {
 Q_OBJECT;
 public:
  pageWidget(int timeout, QWidget *parent = nullptr); // set the first parameter to the timer
 signals:
  void goNext();
  void goPrev();
  void goHome();
 private:
  // emit goHome() when this timer triggered, start in `showEvent()`, stop in `hideEvent()`
  QTimer *timer; 
}


// pageOne.h
// this child class has UI with some buttons
// and connected the clicked signal of the buttons to the signal such as `goNext()`.
class pageOne : public pageWidget{ 
 Q_OBJECT;
}


// mainWindow.cpp
mainWindow::mainWindow(...)
{
 ...
 connect(ui->page_1, &pageWidget::goNext, this, &mainWindow::onGoNext);
 connect(ui->page_2, &pageWidget::goPrev, this, &mainWindow::onGoPrev);
 // other signals such as `goPrev()` and other pages are connected same way.
}

void mainWindow::onGoPrev()
{
 ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->stackedWidget->currentIndex() - 1);
}
```

It works fine. However, when the `goPrev()` signal is received on the first page(index 0), `currentIndex() - 1` is called (meaning the index is set to -1), but `QStackedWidget` ignores it, so nothing happens. But it doesn't make any sense, it's rather unnecessary behavior, so I shouldn't do it. Therefore, the `goPrev()` signal on the first page is not connected, and there is no button for it.
The same goes for the timer that returns to the first page when time elapses. If the time received as an parameter in the constructor of the parent class is 0, the timer is not started, and the first page passes 0.

So the child class(`pageOne`) 'can' work like the parent class(`pageWiget`) if desired, but it is also true that some features of the parent class are missing. Of course, just because I don't click a button doesn't mean it isn't a button. But if ​button that never clicks, it's a label or something else. And it feels like 'I can do this, but I should not' rather than 'I can do this but I don't use it'. It's like using an `array` to implement a `set` that doesn't allow duplicates.

So, Finally, here's my question :
Is this still an 'is-a' relationship? Is public inheritance the right way?

Comment: "*I already finished the implementation I wanted, but I was wondering if this is the right way.*" If your code compiles and works, you might try asking on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: IMO just because you don't do anything when a specific page tells you to go to the previous page doesn't mean it's in any way less a page.  You're just not listening for one of its signals.  I'm not sure the design makes sense in general though.  Why would a page tell the container when to go to the next page?  At first glance it seems like that logic should probably be in the container itself or its controller.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I'm not sure either way, so I keep wondering. The reason the page moves inside the controller is simply a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a stupid question. My thoughts after sleeping for a while is that the behavior of the pageWidget is until it emits a signal, and all page can behavior whether it's the first page or the last page. Whether to use the emitted signal or not is an entirely different matter. Next time I'll sleep a bit more and think again so I don't ask stupid questions.